# Replication from MariaDB(master) to MySQL 5.6 (slave)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Are there any differences in how MariaDB manages replication compared to mySQL 5.6? I mean, are there any differences in configurations or instructions?

I read on MariaDB documentation that replication from MySQL to MariaDB should work but it says nothing about the opposite way. Is it possible to replicate from MariaDB (master) to MySQL 5.6 (slave)?

Comment: not a good idea. why not MariaDB (master) to MariaDB (slave)?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?  You should probably avoid GTIDs.

Comment: There are several scenarios where this is usefull but nobody seems to care. I'm going to try something similar